# Is it possible to write a mobile Safari extension?

Tags: xcode, ios, safari

I wondered is it possible to write mobile safari extensions? XPCOM(NSPR) like extension or javascript based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Extension is not supported in mobile safari. But you can create [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) for mobile safari. It works find in iPhone and iPad, while the install is not so easy like install a bookmarklet on Desktop browsers.

Comment: I know, but from the enduser side the bookmarklet install process is more complicated than a regular desktop browser...